# How to useStyles based on props inside a breakpoint with material-ui

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Let's say I have a very simple `props` interface that specifics a boolean property. Now, in my `useStyles`, I want to change how that style is rendered based on both the conditional property AND a breakpoint. Here's a very simple example:

```
interface Props {
  isError: boolean;
}

const useStyles = makeStyles<Theme, Props>(theme => ({
  box: ({ isError}) => ({
    backgroundColor: isError? 'red' : 'green',

    [theme.breakpoints.up('md')]: {
      backgroundColor: isError ? 'maroon' : 'teal',
    }
  }),
}));
```

When I'm under the `md` breakpoint, this works as expected; but as soon as I go *over* the `md` breakpoint, the color doesn't change. How come?

[Here's a demo on StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-alshuo) that demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In working up the example for this question, I figured out the problem. The property value for creating styles based on a breakpoint, *also* needs to be a function:

```
const useStyles = makeStyles<Theme, Props>(theme => ({
  box: (outerProps) => ({
    backgroundColor: outerProps.isError ? 'red' : 'green',

    [theme.breakpoints.up('md')]: (innerProps) => ({
      backgroundColor: innerProps.isError ? 'maroon' : 'aqua',
    }),
  })
}));
```

[Here's an updated StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-7qiyqh) showing the working example.